# Highchart Solid Gauge Chart make one end straight/normal

Tags: highcharts, angular-highcharts

I'm using Angular-Highcharts and creating solidgauge graph. I wanted to make the start point square/straight and other end rounded. Is it possible to do that with Highcharts? Kindly find below is the live example.
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jym5vrtd/ Fiddle link

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not supported from the basic API options, however, can be done by doing some changes in the `solid-gauge` core code.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tym9xfwb/

Line nr 87:

```
//path[4] = roundStart;
```

You can delete this part of the code from your app.